# Azure Application Gateway with VMSS

Tags: azure, soap

I have deployed a Virtual Machine scaleset with an application gateway. VMs in VMSS has a soap api configured. Now when I download WSDL for my soap api by going through application gateway's DNS name, for soap:addresslocation tag in WSDL it gives privateip of VM as url for example 
`https:\\10.1.0.9:443\servicetag` 
while if I access same API WSDL directly by using DNS name of VM it gives same URL in this for : 
`https\\<VM DNS name>\servicetag`.

Please tell me what is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue after some research into my setup. SO the problem was due to this flag

```
--host-name-from-backend-pool
```

which was setup as true due to which it was picking the hostname of my VM instead of my application gateway frontend IP. setting

```
--host-name-from-backend-pool false
```

as false resolved it